# Python: using regex and tokens with accented chars (negative lookbehind)

Tags: python, regex, python-unicode

I need to detect capitalized words in Spanish, but only when they are not preceeded by a token, which can have unicode chars. (I'm using Python 2.7.12 in linux).

**This works ok (non-unicode token [e.g. guion:]**

```
>>> import regex
>>> s = u"guion: El computador. Ángel."
>>> p = regex.compile( r'(?<!guion:\s) ( [\p{Lu}] [\p{Ll}]+ \b)' , regex.U | regex.X)
>>> print p.sub( r"**\1**", s)
    guion: El computador. **Ángel**.
```

But the same logic **fails to spot accented tokens [e.g. guión:]:**

```
>>> s = u"guión: El computador. Ángel."
>>> p = regex.compile( ur'(?<!guión:\s) ( [\p{Lu}] [\p{Ll}]+ \b)' , regex.U | regex.X)
>>> print p.sub( r"**\1**", s)
guión: **El** computador. **Ángel**.
```

The expected outcome would be:

```
guión: El computador. **Ángel**.
```

In [regex101](https://regex101.com/r/nJ8aX5/4) the code works just fine (in 'pcr (php)' flavor, instead of ['python' flavor](https://regex101.com/r/mpzpFC/1), since for some reason the first seems to give results more similar to those of command line regex package in python).

Is it due to the python version I'm using: 2.7.12 instead of python 3?. 
It is most likely I am misunderstanding something. Thanks in advance for any directions.

After plenty of bugs and weird outcomes, I've come to realize that:

- The `regex` package is the way to go, instead of `re` due to a better
  unicode support (for instance, provides differentiation of upper and
  lowercase unicode chars).
- The `regex.U` flag must be set. ( `regex.X` just allows spaces and comments for the sake of clarity)
- `u''` unicode strings and `r''` raw strings can be combined at the same time: `ur''`
- `\p{Lu}` and `\p{Ll}` match unicode uppercase and lowercase chars, respectively.

Comment: I can't reproduce in Python v3.6.4

Comment: You may be dealing with two different representations of `ó`.  Generally speaking, an accented letter can be represented as either a single precomposed character, or as the base letter followed by a combining accent mark.  The two forms look exactly the same, but don't compare as equal.  Python's `unicodedata` module contains a function for converting Unicode strings to a standard representation.

Comment: Jason's comment might be the key here. Please make sure you pasted the exact text you are testing against and the exact pattern string. For now, the `ó` you are using are the same in the lookbehind and the text, so we cannot repro the issue.